# finding last row in excel and using excel.range

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to use a reference to interop.excel instead of vba to do some worksheet formatting.  My code looks like:

```
    Dim lastrow As Range = excel.Rows.End(XlDirection.xlDown)
    Dim findme As Range = excel.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

the excel.range does not allow me to use the "&" symbol here.  How should I identify my last row of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Range Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_properties%28v=office.11%29.aspx), it seems you just missed to put the `Row` property of the `lastrow` Range:

`Dim findme As Range = excel.Range("A1:A" & lastrow.row)`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but there are a lot of google references with "bad solutions", I think this is the an elegant solution to get the lasCell

```
set lastCell=yourSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

so your code could be:

```
Dim lastrow As Range = excel.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim findme As Range = excel.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

Comment: Not sounding rude, but in effort to educate others, if you think the above is a "bad solution", I think you should explain why. the SpecialCells finds the last cell in a used range vs End property that represents the cell at the end of the region that contains the source range. I think it depends on what you want to achieve and within which constraints do you want to do it in.

Answer (score 0):

lastrow is defined as a Range and you are trying to do a string concatenation between a string and a Range.

Comment: AH! thanks!  I ended up with:        

`Dim endrow As Range = excel.Rows.End(XlDirection.xlDown)`

      `Dim lastrow As Integer = endrow.Row`


        `Dim cells As Range = excel.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)`

Now my next question would be, which column does excel.rows.end(xldirection.xldown) search for? Or does it extend to the absolute last row in the entire spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

It looks at "A".  But beware, if there is a merged cell going vertical, it takes the top cell of the merger.  So if there is a merged cell going from A15 to A20 which is the last cell of the column, it will then classify A15 as the last cell even though its A20.  I find that Neolisk's solution is the best in a case like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Bayldon  It ends at last row where there is an entry. It skips blanks also. I am using VB.NET 2010. Here is the sample code.

```
Dim r2 As Excel.Range
Dim lastrow As Integer

r2 = oSheet.Range("Task_ID") 'Task_ID is my column name
lastrow = r2.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'returns last row
```